# Snakemake split folder

Tags: python, snakemake

I'm aware of the use of `checkpoints` in `Snakemake` for splitting files and working on them separately.

However, is there something like this for `folders`? For example, I have a folder with 30000 files.

I would like to create `10 folders with 3000 files each`. Other downstream analyses will proceed on these folders

I would prefer the approach to be generic though, so if I have 45000 files in another run, the output should be `15 folders with 3000 files in each`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you provide additional details? Specifically, I'm not sure if what you're looking to create is a job for a Python code block inside the Snakefile.

Comment: Not sure what additional details you require, but I would like to create a rule that takes as an input a single folder with files within, and output multiple folders with a subset of those files.